# res in this code is not being updated. Can anyone please tell the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, string, math

```
let x = '3+Math.sqrt(345+32'
let res = '';
for(var i = 0;i < x.length;++i){
    if(x==="("){
        for(var j = i + 1;j < x.length;++j){
            if(/[+-/%*]/g.test(x[j])){
               res = x.slice(0,i+1) + x.slice(i+1,j) + ")" + x.slice(j);
                break;
            }
        }
        continue;
    }
}
```

> 1.The res variable is not changing
>
> 2.Second for loop is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking if `x==="("` instead of `x[i]==="("`

```js
let x = '3+Math.sqrt(345+32'
let res = '';
for(var i = 0;i < x.length;++i){
    if(x[i]==="("){
        for(var j = i + 1;j < x.length;++j){
            if(/[+-/%*]/g.test(x[j])){
               res = x.slice(0,i+1) + x.slice(i+1,j) + ")" + x.slice(j);
                break;
            }
        }
        continue;
    }
}

console.log(res)
```